# Is there a Korean equivalent to the verb "to google"?

Tags: word-choice, verb

Google search engine being dominant, the verb "to google" is commonly used to mean "to search using Google", or more generally "to search on Internet".

**Is there a Korean equivalent fo this verb in Korean?**

Funnily, I could not find the answer using Google... the only thing I could find is that there is a 구글링 (Googling) entry on the Korean Wikipedia. I cannot fully understand it but it seems to be on the Western use. I am not sure if it says it is common in Korea or if a verb (구글하다 maybe?) exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Korean *verbing* slang history

It's a common thing in English *to verb <sub>(I mean ‘verb’ as a verb.)</sub>* nouns, no matter whether they can be *actually done* or not. For example,
 [`grenade` is not a thing can be done, but we would be able to say `this is like, my fifth time I've 'naded you.`](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78354/which-nouns-can-be-used-as-verbs) in [*CS: GO*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive). In Korean, however, it isn't.

Verbing *un-doable* nouns, is quite unusual in Korean. It can be barely found in [some quite recent Korean slangs](https://namu.wiki/w/%E2%97%8B%E2%97%8B%EB%8B%B9%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4), since [the `I·SEOUL·U` meme](http://brandinginasia.com/i-seoul-you-the-confusing-new-slogan-for-seoul/) was created in 2016.

[image: The <code>I·SEOUL·U</code> meme]

---

## The only thing we have is the noun

Korean has **only** a noun ***equivalent*** (slang) of `to google`: `구글링` [<sub>Romanized:</sub> gugeulling]. It means, well, `googling`; searching on *Google*, not any other search engines. There's **no** verb equivalent of it, such as `구글하다`.

So the best you can do to express `to google` in Korean, would be **`구글링 하다`**; `to do googling`. **This is extremely common and natural to use.** Note that, it's not a single word, so you have to space it between `구글링` (`googling`) and `하다` (`to do`).

---

## See also

- A linguistic term [영변화 (零變化, *zero derivation* (*conversion*).)](https://ko.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%98%81%EB%B3%80%ED%99%94): (of a word) changing the part of speech without any modification applied.

Comment: "It's common thing in English to verb nouns". I see what you did here hh. Great answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is.

For example,

> **구글링** 해 봐~ **googling**
>
> 구글 검색 해 봤어? / 구글에 검색해 봤어? Did you search on google?
>
> 구글에 쳐 봐 means literally typing on Google, but it actually means searching on Google.

검색 means to search.
구글링 is google + ing and Korean people use `ing` for when doing something (`present participle`)

(I have 26 years of experience in Korean.)

Comment: Please edit if I made some grammar mistake :p I been using English for 6 years.

Comment: Thank you. Is this for a search specifically using Google? Or any search on internet?

Comment: when people mention Google it means google search engine. Otherwise there is famous search engine name `Naver`. In that case we say 네이버에 검색해봐 ( search on Naver)